# git untracked file error on branch change

Tags: git, version-control

I'm trying to switch branches on a newly-cloned repo on my Windows machine:

```
$ git checkout hybridClass
error: Updating the following directories would lose untracked files in it:
    Scripts\/

Aborting
```

my commits are current:

```
git commit -m "message"
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I can't seem to find these untracked files:

```
git clean -d -n
```

(no output)

I have successfully checked out this branch before (on another machine), so I'm not sure what's going on here. My apologies if this is a duplicate; none of the similar posts seemed to be quite appropriate.

Edit: added `git status` output

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: What does `git status` say?

Comment: Is there a `Scripts\ ` or `Scripts` directory in the top level of the working tree? What does it contain?

Comment: Yes; it is where most of my tracked files are. mostly python and R scripts, as well as some queue manager batch job scripts and output files from them. Everything was staged with `git add .` before my commit that isn't in .gitignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> git clean -d -n

Add the `-x` flag to your clean to remove the untracked files as well

> **-x**
>
> Don’t use the standard ignore rules read from .gitignore (per directory) and $GIT_DIR/info/exclude, but do still use the ignore rules given with -e options. This allows removing all untracked files, including build products.
>
> This can be used (possibly in conjunction with git reset) to create a pristine working directory to test a clean build.

Comment: Is there any reason this would behave differently on Win vs. *nix/OSX? I tried this on a non-Windows machine and it behaved as expected.

Comment: Git doesnt care on which OS its running, its the same, GIT is basically unix based :-)

Comment: I thought this should be the case. Still, my Linux box and my MacBook both performed as expected, while my Windows machine continued to give me problems, even after a fresh clone. Strange. Anyway, thanks.