Getting error: Updating the following directories would lose untracked files in them
I cloned a repo from Bitbucket and installed the project locally.
no new change was available in my local repo. no changes in the stash.
but when I am doing checkout the branch, the error msg is showing
I:\proj\framework>git checkout development
error: Updating the following directories would lose untracked files in them:
        src/services/oam/oam_module/\

Aborting

how can I fixed this.

Does any of these help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34528109/git-untracked-file-error-on-branch-change or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42373656/git-pull-yields-error-updating-the-following-directories-would-lose-untracked

The error message is occurring because Git is safeguarding your untracked files. The directory src/services/oam/oam_module/ includes files that Git does not track, and if you switch to the development branch, it could overwrite these files.
You can use the command git status to see what these untracked files are. If these files are important, you should add and commit them to your current branch.
git status
git add src/services/oam/oam_module/<file>
git commit -m "Add untracked files"

If the untracked files are not important, you can remove them. You can add the -n to git clean command to run a dry run which will not actually remove anything, just show what would be done.
git clean -f -d -x -n 

Then you can decide if you need to remove them.
git clean -f -d -x 

After performing one of these operations, you should be able to checkout to the development branch without any issues.
